# Can I install android app on Google TV Development box?

Tags: google-tv

I have a google tv development box. Can I install an app on that? If so, how?

Comment: Did you try setting it up with the USB interface?   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

Comment: The accepted answer is no longer valid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately the LogiciTech Revue Google TV does not connect via adb.

This answer was helpful for connecting abd over tcpip:
[How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)

Comment: Looks like there has been an update.  Although this link does not specifically discuss the Logitech Revue wrt to ADB and debugging over TCPIP.

Answer (score 3):

You can now use adb to connect and install your app for 3.1:

https://code.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_debug.html

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the ability to install apps and develop android apps will come when they upgrade the devices to Android 3.1

For the moment I don't think you are able to do much else than web testing.

Comment: I have the developer box they gave away at GoogleIO with android 3.1 but there is no information on how to install an app.