# Is it possible to develop Google TV apps using a Mac and an actual Google TV device?

Tags: emulation, google-tv, android

I don't want to use Linux to use the emulator. Is it possible to use an actual device instead?

If possible, please, show me the references you used to answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I install android app on Google TV Development box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970989/can-i-install-android-app-on-google-tv-development-box)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. But instead of using the traditional USB method, you must debug over IP (this means that both your computer and the Google TV must be on the same network)

To start with, we will assume you have a Google TV and a Workstation [your Mac]

1. On your Google TV, open Settings, and go to Applications -> Development.
2. Turn **Remote debugging** on
3. Click **Debugger IP address** and enter the IP of **your Workstation** (if you have DHCP enabled on your router, you will need to look this up)
4. Find the IP address of your Google TV [it's available in Settings -> Network -> Status]
5. On your Workstation, run:

   `adb connect <Google TV IP Address>`
6. If you got everything right, you will now be able to debug on Google TV just like any other device...

#### Caveats...

- If you for some reason want to disconnect later, run: `adb disconnect <Google TV IP Address>`
- If the IP of your Workstation ever changes, you will need to update this on the Google TV [step 3 above]

Source: [Google TV developer guide here](http://code.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_debug.html)

Comment: +1 for answering my question, but the OP is asking about emulators not debugging against an actual device, right?

Comment: @shanabus As far as I can tell he's actually asking about a "device." Especially considering the title he used... Or am I reading something incorrectly?

Comment: you are completely right, I'll stop posting comments when its time for bed.  I was looking for a question/answer on installing the emulator on Mac or Windows and so I was interpreting it all wrong.

Answer (score 1):

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-futures-creating-android-apps-for-google-tv/

Yes it is very much possible to use a device instead, please read the aforementioned link more specifically the section on testing:

> **Testing Your Application**
>
> As there is no emulator yet available with a true Google TV Android
>   image,  we can only test the effects of the higher screen resolution
>   and using the  application with a touch screen.
>
> The easiest way to do this is to create a new AVD using Android 3.1,
>   API Level 12,  use a resolution of 1920×1080 (or 1280×720), and use a
>   touch screen setting of false.  The performance of the emulators may
>   make this difficult, but at least you can get an  idea of what the
>   screen will look like and how the navigation or your application will 
>   function without touch.

Answer (score 1):

The only option now is having a Goole TV device and setting it up for debugging mode,

Also there is currently a [topic in the Google TV issues asking for the Mac OS emulator](http://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/issues/detail?id=28&q=Type%3DEnhancement&sort=-stars&colspec=ID+Stars+Type+Status+Summary&#makechanges).

You can star the issue to receive updates about it and also help to request this feature.